# Is UDP now allowed on most cellular/mobile networks?

Tags: udp, cellular-network

I want to make an app for smartphones that will send and receive UDP packets to and from a publicly accessible server (so not peer-to-peer, and no need for holepunching).

There's bunches of questions about this but they are all old and vague. I want to know if thing changed since.

Does anyone know a list of mobile networks that now allow UDP? And in a more general way, does most network allow UDP (in US, EU and Asia)?